# Motivation and Meaning of a Quotient Space

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Let $V$ be some space and $W$ a subspace, we usually define the quotient space as $V/W$. If $V$ is a group under $+$ and $W$ a subgroup, then we write $V/W = [ {v+W| v \in V }] $ what is the motivation behind this and what is the meaning of this? Or let me put it this way, how to visualise the quotient space intuitively? Or maybe in layman terms.

Comment: One short answer is as follows.  Geometrically, we can think of $V/W$ as consisting of planes in $V$ parallel to $W$.  We note in particular that adding to planes gives you the third whenever adding any two vectors from the added planes lands you in the third.  Regarding motivation, ultimately we want to be able to go from statements about linear maps to statements about isomorphisms; with that in mind, $W$ is typically the kernel of some linear map.

Comment: When we form the quotient space $V/W$, it is as if we are setting the elements of $W$ equal to $0$. When we do this, any two elements of $V$ which differ only by an element of $W$ are now considered to be equal. A slightly different way to say it is that we are declaring the elements of $W$ to be somehow unimportant, so that if $v_1 = v_2 + w$, for some $w \in W$, then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are now considered to be equivalent. $V/W$ is like a simplified, coarse view of $V$, where elements of $W$ are considered to be unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient space partitions your group. Meaning it divides/subsections your group into subsets all of the same order -- known as cosets.

Consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$
let your subgroup be the multiples of three, that is:
$$ \{z \mid z=3n \ \ \text{for some}\ \ n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$

then $13=1+3 \cdot 4$ and $22=1+3 \cdot 7$ both belong to the same coset. Since they are both of the form $1+3n$. similarly, all numbers of the form $3n$ and $3n+2$ belong in the same coset. We have just taken the integers, based on your definition of a quotient space,  and divided/partitioned it into subsets